# Django Crispy Forms: Replace Label and Radio Buttons with Images

Tags: forms, django-forms, radio-button, django-crispy-forms

I have a form where a certain field is a radio selector with 3 options. Let's say this represents Good, More-or-Less, and Bad.

I managed to put them in the same line with InlineRadio, like this:

```
self.helper.layout = Layout(InlineRadio(field_name))
```

Now, I need to 2 things:

1) replace each option, that is rendered as a radio-button and its label with a pre-defined image.

2) Add 2 images, one to the left and one to the right of the radio buttons. So, at the end, I'll have 5 images in a row. From left to right: `Image of Smile (just the image)` - `Image of selector (Good)` - `Image of selector (More-or-Less)` - `Image of selector (Bad)` - `Image of Sad face (just the image`)

Is it possible to achieve them with django-crispy? If not, how can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm the lead developer of crispy-forms. You could do this using `Field` layout object and using a custom template.

```
Field('field_name', template="custom_inline_radio.html")
```

Other option you have is to create your own layout object subclassing `InlineRadio`. That way you would only have to do:

```
CustomInlineRadio('field_name')
```

Actually, what you try to do is basically override the output of a default widget in Django and that probably makes more sense if you use a custom widget in your Django form, crispy-forms will play great with it. I wrote an article on [widgets and Django forms](http://tothinkornottothink.com/post/10815277049/django-forms-i-custom-fields-and-widgets-in-detail) that might interest you.

Comment: I have solved this by subclassing the InlineRadio. This allowed me to not only customize the template, but also pass other context variables. I was going to post it here, but you did before me. Thanks for the awesome package!